# Creating dynamic variable names in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dynamic, csv

I am trying to write a simple role playing game in C# to become more familiar with the language.

I have a class that loads data from CSV file, creates an object, and places it in a dictionary. Because every aspect of the game has different data (items, actors, skills, etc), I have set up each of these as a class, but this requires me to re-implement a Load() method for each one. After doing this 5 or 6 times, I am wondering if there isn't a better way to implement this.

Basically, what I would want to do is parse over the first line of the CSV which contains headers, and use these as class variable names. Currently, they are implemented as a dictionary relationship, so I would do SomeClassInstance.dict["id"], where I would ideally type SomeClassInstance.id, which is entirely generated from the contents of the file.

Is that a thing? How do I do this?

Comment: You could use reflection to iterate through the class properties, test if the name of the property matches the name of the CSV column, and then set the value. Maybe AutoMapper can help, but I'm not sure, you'd have to read a bit about it

Comment: Don't make a botch in your design just in order to simplify persistance!

Comment: @AndreCalil That leads to some pretty ugly code: http://pastebin.com/uK5E4XMS

Comment: @James (1) Ugly code isn't necessarily bad code. (2) It could be rewritten to be *prettier* anyway. (3) When someone asks a question, I do not intend to change the scenario. If OP is storing data using CSV, well, keep at let's focus on the question. I he asked "is there a better persistence approach?", things would be very different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you stick to your current design (CSV + dictionary) you could use the ExpandoObject class to get what you are looking for, create a simple factory class:

```
public static class ObjectFactory
{
    public static dynamic CreateInstance(Dictionary<string, string> objectFromFile)
    {
        dynamic instance = new ExpandoObject();

        var instanceDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)instance;

        foreach (var pair in objectFromFile)
        {
            instanceDict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

This factory will create an object instance of whatever dictionary you give it, i.e. just one method to create all your different kinds of objects. Use it like this:

```
   // Simulating load of dictionary from file
   var actorFromFile = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   actorFromFile.Add("Id", "1");
   actorFromFile.Add("Age", "37");
   actorFromFile.Add("Name", "Angelina Jolie");

   // Instantiate dynamically
   dynamic actor = ObjectFactory.CreateInstance(actorFromFile);

   // Test using properties
   Console.WriteLine("Actor.Id = " + actor.Id + 
                     " Name = " + actor.Name + 
                     " Age = " + actor.Age);
   Console.ReadLine();
```

Hopes this helps. (And yes she was born 1975)

Comment: That is pretty interesting. I like the idea, it seems to simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 7):

You need to read up on [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) - instead of holding the files in CSV files, you can store them in a serialized format and load them *directly* into the wanted type.

You will only need a couple of methods to serialize and deserialize.

I suggest reading up on:

- [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)
- [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)
- [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)
- [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)
- [protobuf.net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)
- [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

The above links are to different serializers (and I have certainly left some off - anyone in the know, if there is a good serializer that you know, please add)  - read through, see their APIs, play around with them and see their on-disk formats and make your decision.

Answer (score 1):

Derive from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject) and override `TryGetMember` so that it returns the appropriate dictionary entry. Exactly what Microsoft did in MVC 3's ViewBag.
Example usage (if your derived type was named `CsvBag`):

```
dynamic bag = new CsvBag(csvFileStream);
_monitor.Monster.LookUp(*bag.Id*).Attack(player); // whatever..
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a manager object responsible for reading data and returning instances of specified objects? Something like:

```
var actors = ActorsLoader.Load("actors.cvs");
```

where ActorsLoader.Load could be implemented as:

```
IEnumerable<Actor> Load( string fileName )
{
    //1. reading each line (each line = new actor) & creating actor object
    //2. adding created actor object to a collection
    //3. returning back a collection
}
```

I have assumed that each type of in-game objects are stored in separate files (so that you have: actors.csv, items.csv, skills.csv etc.)

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I have (sorry if my OP post was ambiguous to that effect). It's actually ActorData which contains a dictionary of <int, Actor>. However, the load constructors are different...

Mine isn't IEnumerable<Actor>, but just a public void.

Comment: ah sorry for misunderstanding. So what you actually want to do is to get rid of the serialization / deserialization code at all? if you wan to have some auto de-serialization mechanism in place maybe looking at cvs de-serializer that ServiceStack uses will be of help? http://www.servicestack.net/docs/text-serializers/json-csv-jsv-serializers

Comment: I believe that might be what I want ... I basically want to create a class dynamically with data from a file. Like, it's members would be completely determined from the file.

Since your answer and a few others also mention serialization, I suppose I should read up on this further.

Comment: I don't think you can serialize/deserialize dynamic objects, you would have to create regular non dynamic classes for it to work.