# C# Dynamic List Name

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create few list in c# but want to name those list dynamically according to some condition.

For example

```
List<string> x1= new List<string>();
List<string> x2 = new List<string>();
```

The name "x1" and "x2" would come at runtime (probably from some file or something). Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do that dynamic variable names is your "solution" to that problem.

Comment: This is bad programming practice. Your variable names shouldn't be user-determined. Marcin provides an acceptable solution, but you should just avoid this altogether. What is it you want to do?

Comment: Hah. I didn't realise there was a term for this. Thanks @ScottChamberlain... I will be using that in future!

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher, look at the selected answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891381/creating-dynamic-variable-names-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I am trying to read an excel file which could contain any numbers of columns.I would be putting contents of these rows/columns into the list created.Since i dont know how many columns could be there i wanted to do it this way. Any suggestions to achieve this in better way ?

Comment: Can't you just create a new class `Column` which holds fields `ColumnName` and `List<T> entries`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

dict["x1"] = new List<string>();
```

You can replace `"x1"` with variable.

Comment: Nice solution to the problem.