# Using variable in label name

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, label

Can something like this be done?

```
var test = 1;

label+test+.Text = "Some text goes here...";
```

Which would result in:

```
label1.Text = "Some text goes here...";
```

I wouldn't mind using switch-case if I had few cases, but I have like 40 labels that I would like dynamically assigned text depending on the variable value.

Comment: It's possible, you will need to use dynamic objects like ExpandoObject. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891381/creating-dynamic-variable-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: @William What would an Expando object do here? Not a lot....

Comment: @William while dynamic object may work, using dictionary directly is much more common approach to this problem (and would be much easier to get right)... As in CSV sample you've linked `dynamic` would be nicer for single row  rather than  also for table itself...

Comment: The basic answer is: No this is not valid c# syntax. But there are workarounds. Before jumping on them in the answers better re-think your layout and setup! If you want to process a number of controls, make them accessible in a suitable data structure like a List<Label> or a Dictionary<string, Label>..!

Answer (score 4):

Use Controls.Find() in your form.

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = 1;
    var labels = Controls.Find("label" + test, true);
    if (labels.Length > 0)
    {
        var label = (Label) labels[0];
        label.Text = "Some text goes here...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have like 40 labels that I would like dynamically assigned text
> depending on the variable value

Here's another example, which is basically the same approach as Handoko's:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
{
    Label lbl = this.Controls.Find("label" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    if (lbl != null)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Hello Label #" + i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = 1;
Control label = this.FindControl("label" + test);
if(label != null)
{
  label.Text = "Some text goes here...";
}
```

More informationon FindControl is available at,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol%28v=VS.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396