# creating a variable using string VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2008

I have this code (Written in VB.net):

```
        Dim Text As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\Name Of Varible.txt")
        Dim Text As String
```

When i did

```
Dim Text As String
```

the second time, i didn't meant for the variable's name to be "Text", I meant it to be the value of the variable Text, that i declared.

```
Dim Text As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\Name Of Variable.txt")
```

If you could please help me it would be great!

A code in C# or VB.net would be great, Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just to see if I understand, you want the **name** of the variable to be a value of another variable?

Comment: do you mean you can first variable "Text" is the value of the second line variable?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, nor can I imagine any scenario where it would be desired...

Comment: @ZoharPeled For each picturebox As Control In Me.Controls Create a variable named the name of the picturebox + "1"   For example: PictureboxExample1 As Picturebox

Comment: @TalV, you don't need dynamically named variables. You are not the first to ever use a collection of controls. Maybe you can make use of the `Tag` property but we really don't know what your goal is.

Comment: I agree with Crowcoder - There are collections for such things, there is no need to dynamically name variables. If there was such a need, it would be possible already.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dynamic variable names in c# or vb if what you need is changing instance fields you can use reflection`

```
object value = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(obj);
```

Comment: @miliadQasemi How do you use reflection?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this. However, you can create a Dictionary and fill the values in runtime.

There is a nice answer on StackOverflow :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892907/4848251